# How do I import data as an array from a .csv file into a mongodb collection in Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongodb-atlas, compass, mongoimport

I want to import data into a mongodb collection in an Atlas instance with some data stored in an array.  The data is initially is stored in a table in a .csv file like this:

| name | age | interests.0 | interests.1 | interests.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David | 24 | Jogging | Swimming |  |
| Sarah | 43 | Movies | Football | Netball |

If I import it via compass, it imports correctly and the data looks like:

```
{
 name : 'David',
 age:24, 
 interests : [
    0: "Jogging",
    1: "Swimming",
 ]
},
{
 name : 'Sarah',
 age:43, 
 interests : [
    0: "Movies",
    1: "Football",
    2: "Netball"
 ]
}
```

But compass requires me to manually select the type of each column which is time consuming.  If I use `mongoimport` with the following command:

```
mongoimport --uri 'mongodb+srv://cluster0.xxx.mongodb.net/my_db' \
   --username='user' \
   --collection='my_collection' \
   --ignoreBlanks \
   --type=csv \
   --headerline \
   --file=/url-to-my-data/data.csv
```

It does not require the data type to be manually selected, but the interests column becomes an object, e.g.:

```
interests : {
    0: "Movies",
    1: "Football",
    2: "Netball"
}
```

How can I import the data from the format it is currently in, in the .csv file but avoid the manual data type selection compass requires and keep the interests column as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I have found for this is to import the data with `mongoImport` and modify the objects to arrays after they are imported as follows:

1. Import the .csv using `mongoImport` as in the question above.
2. Access the Atlas instance using `mongosh`
3. Use the following command to update the interests object to an array:

```
db.my_collection.find({}).forEach(doc => {   
    if(doc.interests){
        let interestsArray = Object.values(doc.interests); 
        db.my_collection.updateOne({"_id": doc._id}, [{$set:{ "interests" : interestsArray}}]); 
    }
});
```

The if statement is used to check if the document has an `interests` field, otherwise `Object.values()` throws an error. This is helpful if using it to modify lots of documents and some might not have an `interests` field because the command would stop on the first document to not have an `interests` field.